# Duración de Audio - Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

necesito que mis audios duren solo 20 segundos en el reproductor de audio de mi tema DIVI, en wordpress.
¿Podrían ayudame sobre qué código usar en la configuración avanzada de mis módulos? o en dónde debo hacerlo?
soy novato, les agradeceré infinitamente ...
Saludos

Comment: Hola Nico, bienvenido a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Answer (score 0):

Código:

```
settimeout -> 20'' 
$('audio').each(function(){
    this.pause(); // Stop playing
    this.currentTime = 0; // Reset time
});
```

Comment: Agrega una descripción de que realiza el código, ver [answer].